# Use lapply with readLines on Variable Length Input

Tags: json, r, parallel-processing, readline

I have a text file where each line is a JSON object.  I can read a specifc file into R quite easily:

```
lapply(readLines(FILE, n=N, warn=FALSE), fromJSON)
```

This is probably straightforward, but I want to take this function and apply it across a number of FILES in parallel

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: do you already have a list for the files, with appropriate path?

Comment: Wrap in another ```lapply```: ```lapply(FILES, function(FILE) lapply(readLines(FILE, n=N, warn=FALSE), fromJSON))```

Comment: @jbaums wont that make for a pretty nasty list?

Comment: @RicardoSaporta well, it'll return a list, each element of which is a list containing elements that are returned by ```fromJSON```.

Comment: @RicardoSaporta I do.  My idea is that I would pass a vector of file paths to the function.  But as pointed out in the comments, this could be a nasty nest list situation.  In the end, all I want is one list entry for each row in the text files.  My hope was that I could leverage multi-core processing.

Comment: To "un-nest" the output you should be able to ```unlist(x, recursive=F)``` the result. To do this in parallel, though, see ```parSapply``` in ```parallel```. See below for a possible parallel solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one solution using `parLapply`:

```
f <- function(x) lapply(readLines(x, n=N, warn=FALSE), fromJSON)
library(parallel)
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores())
unlist(parLapply(cl, FILES, f), recursive=FALSE)
# where FILES is a vector of file paths
```

Comment: Thanks for help.  The code above produced the following error:  Error ```in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
  2 nodes produced errors; first error: object 'fromJSON' not found``` but fromJSON is loaded

Comment: Actually, I believe I figured it out using this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10095956/parsapply-not-finding-objects-in-global-environment).  For me, the fix was ```clusterExport(cl, c("fromJSON", "N", "FILES"))``` in which N is a parameter to tell readLines how many lines to read.  The character string threw me for a moment, but it appears to work.  Thanks for this!